# How can I get an event from Pusher using Starscream on Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, websocket, pusher

I'm trying to use Pusher for my iOS app. I installed Starscream.framework into my app as client side. I was able to connect to the specific Pusher's app. And also I was able to disconnect it by tapping a button on my app. I can watch these activities and logs from Debug Console of Pusher.

But, if I create new event from Debug Console, my iOS app doesn't receive it event."websocketDidReceiveMessage" function will not work. [Image of Debug Console](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5IBVvvQoqCNdTVEWXFOaDRqd2c&authuser=0)

I think that I made mistake. Please tell me if there is some kind of mistake.

Best regards.

Here is my code.

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import Starscream

class ViewController: UIViewController, WebSocketDelegate {


var socket = WebSocket(url: NSURL(scheme: "ws", host: "ws.pusherapp.com/app/API_KEY?protocol=7", path: "/")!)


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.socket.delegate = self
    self.socket.connect()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@IBAction func disconnectWasTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    self.socket.disconnect()
}


// MARK: WebSocket
func websocketDidConnect(socket: WebSocket) {
    println("websocket is connected")
}

func websocketDidDisconnect(socket: WebSocket, error: NSError?) {
    println("websocket is disconnected: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
}

func websocketDidReceiveMessage(socket: WebSocket, text: String) {
    //println("got some text!!")
    println("got some text: \(text)")
}

func websocketDidReceiveData(socket: WebSocket, data: NSData) {
    println("got some data: \(data.length)")
}


}
```

**UPDATE**
I was able to fix my problem by my self. I decided not to use Pusher. I decided to use PubNub instead Pusher. It is working on Swift now. And it is really easy to integrate with Parse to realize the realtime communication.